# Extract set of values from collection of maps by specific keys

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to extract set of values from collection of maps by specific keys. For example,

Input:

```
[
    {:k1 "v1" :k2 "v2" :k3 "v3"} 
    {:k1 "v4" :k2 "v2"}
]
```

Assuming that getting set of values by :k1, :k2

Desired output:

```
#{"v1" "v2" "v4"}
```

So my solution is

```
(->> [{:k1 "v1" :k2 "v2" :k3 "v3"}
      {:k1 "v4" :k2 "v2"}]
     (map #(-> (select-keys % [:k1 :k2]) (vals) (set)))
     (apply clojure.set/union))
```

But I wanna know better ways. What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `into` and a transducer, we can do the following:

```
(def input [{:k1 "v1" :k2 "v2" :k3 "v3"} {:k1 "v4" :k2 "v2"}])
(into #{} (mapcat (juxt :k1 :k2)) input) => #{"v4" "v1" "v2"}
```

Alternatively, we can use the composition of `cat` and `map` in lieu of `mapcat`:

```
(into #{} (comp (map (juxt :k1 :k2)) cat) input) => #{"v4" "v1" "v2"}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's really nice for me, more clear and concise. :)